# Setting Font Size Does Not Respect adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

Tags: ios, objective-c, scale, uifont

I'm setting the font size and weight of a label:

```
self.title.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24 weight:UIFontWeightSemibold];
self.title.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.title.minimumScaleFactor = 0.4;
```

However, the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is not respected. When I set the font size and weight the font does not scale down to fit the width of the label. When I don't set the font size and weight it scales down. How can I get the label to scale down while providing a default size and weight?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem too and the trick is you can provide numberOfLines > 1 and try to set your default systemFontOfSize smaller.

Also, remember to check your constraint of the UIView to make sure adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth works.